# A project can't reference another project of the same solution

Tags: c#-4.0

Suppose I create a Class Library named ClassLibrary1, and then right click the solution and add another class library named ClassLibrary2.

[image]

I find that any class in ClassLibrary1 can't reference any other class in ClassLibrary2 and vice versa.

[image]

How can I reference a solution from the other?, I'm supposing than as long as they belong in the same solution they can be cross referenced...

Rafael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also right click the in the references section of the target library and click "Add Reference". Ihe the dialog, select the project you want to reference.

So, if you are in ClassLibrary1 and want to reference items in ClassLibrary2 then you have to right-click the references section in ClassLibrary1 and go to the "Projects" section and double-click ClassLibrary2 in the list.

See here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rs4ovgC0Wmw

Comment: This actually does not work as it results in an error message: "A reference to <ClassLibrary2> could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced."

Comment: I don't know what you are seeing, but it definitely works for me. Here's a video I took: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rs4ovgC0Wmw

Comment: It turns out that I was creating the wrong type of project, and if you do that, you get that error message.  So the projects refering to each other apparently have to be of compatible types.  Needless to say, right now I'm not too impressed with Visual Studio's error messaging.

Comment: Error messaging on any platform is unimpressive if you don't understand the context of the error message. It might help to know what the two project types you have are, and in which direction the reference was being made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a *reference* to the ClassLibrary2 project (asssembly).

You will then be able to use namespaces and types in that project.

Right-click the other project, then click Add Reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022:

A contrived example solution with two projects:

[image]

Right Click and Choose Add Project Reference:

[image]

Choose the Project that the Project you right clicked on Depends on:

[image]

And Voila:

[image]

In this example the **Website** depends on the **Data Access Layer**, therefore we choose the website and add a dependency to the DAL.